# Retriev Data from Persisten Object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I have a problem understanding Hibernate. I got a Object from my Database.
e.g a Java object like this, created by calling a Hibernate function:
Person: 
id,forename,name etc.

When I got that Object I like write it into a HashMap and to print it as a Json, the only thing I get is:
"de.test.carSharing.Person@7eab0d73"

I don't know why, because I can access all Values desperately but not the Person Object.

Can anyone give me a Hint?

I'm using a Hibernate XML Mapping and my Transaction is alright.
I'm very thankful for any Answer.

Comment: can you add some code to understand the question. When you print an object then it calls the toString() method of that object so if you have not overridden that method then you will get the class name combined with its hashcode.

Comment: Its all made from HQL Commands only Selects in HQL.

Comment: What do you mean by printing it as a JSON? It seems you are just passing the object reference to `System.out` then it just calls the toString method of that object, so there is no issue.

Comment: Im trying to print the Values as Json with the Fasterxml library. From the base Object im getting all i want but when i put that Object into a HashMap its gonna give me only the String of the Instance like:de.test.carSharing.Person@7eab0d73

Answer (score 0):

The Solution: I packed the content into a Wrapper Pojo and it works.